# rundeck cli : get job output in my script

Tags: command-line-interface, rundeck

I'm starting a job from the cli, using rundeck-cli :

```
bash-4.2# java -jar rundeck-cli-2.0.5-all.jar   run --id 5a8e123456XXXXXf2b60
1514611 succeeded 2023-05-26T14:41:02Z 2023-05-26T14:41:04Z http://${RD_URL}/project/Test/execution/show/1514611 job 5a8e123456XXXXXf2b60 /MyJob
```

I can retrieve info about the job :

```
bash-4.2# java -jar rundeck-cli-2.0.5-all.jar executions  info --eid=1514611
failedNodes:
  description: sudo -u rambo -i /opt/tools/commands.sh ('MyJob')
  project: Nextgen
  successfulNodes:
    node1.example.com

  argstring:
  serverUUID: 43bc083
  dateStarted: 2023-05-26T14:41:02Z
  dateEnded: 2023-05-26T14:41:04Z
  id: 1514611
  href: http://${RD_URL}/api/37/execution/1514611
  permalink: http://${RD_URL}/project/Test/execution/show/1514611
  job:
    id: 5a8e123456XXXXXf2b60
    name: MyJob
    group:
    project: Test
    href: http://${RD_URL}/api/37/job/5a8e123456XXXXXf2b60
    permalink: http://${RD_URL}/project/Nextgen/job/show/5a8e123456XXXXXf2b60
    description:
    averageDuration: 2423

  adhoc: false
  user: admin
  status: succeeded
```

But I did not find yet how to retrieve the job ouptut, that I can see in the gui  in `http://${RD_URL}/project/Test/execution/show/1514611#output`

I need this output in my script to retrieve some data.

When I try to use the `follow` option, after the job has finished, I only get the last line of the job output.

```
bash-4.2# java -jar rundeck-cli-2.0.5-all.jar executions  follow --eid=1514611
         ============================= DONE FOR Test ==========================================
```

How can I download the output file ?

Comment: I tried with `rd run -f -j YourJob -p YourProject` command successfully (I can see the [full job output](https://imgur.com/UrTkEGC), not only the last line). Could you share a job definition example to test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just put the `-f` option to run call:

my short cli-version:

```
rd run --id=<id> -f
```

your long jar version:

```
java -jar rundeck-cli-2.0.5-all.jar   run --id 5a8e123456XXXXXf2b60 -f
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had not run the job with the `follow` option, but only checked the `executions` , once the job was over. Actually, I had not seen the -f option was available for the run. Thank you.